# Trouble with javascript click() method / html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thank you in advance for looking at this.

My webapp allows a user to select choices from four different drop-down menus. When the user makes a selection, the program successfully performs the following `click()` function which creates a new `span` element within a `div` element:

```
var activeFilterNames = [];
   $('.filter').click(function()
      {
        if (!this.classList.contains('disabled'))
          {  
          //above checks to see if link has already been clicked 
          //and is therefore disabled. If not, go ahead.

            activeFilterNames.push(this.textContent); 
            //above adds name of selected link to array 

            i = activeFilterNames.length;                                       
            var newFilter = document.createElement('span');
            newFilter.id = activeFilterNames[i-1];
            newFilter.className = this.className+" activated";
            //above adds a new class to identify the filter as 'activated'
            //above retains existing classname to identify
            //which of the four filters it came from

            newFilter.innerHTML = activeFilterNames[i-1];                                                                                                                           
            //above creates display text to be rendered in browser

            document.getElementById('active_filters').appendChild(newFilter);
            //above is the div in which span will be appended to other spans.

            $("#active_filters > span").removeClass('filter');
            //above removes .filter class so that this newly created span does
            //not respond to the .filter click() function.

            $(this).addClass('disabled');                                       
            //above adds 'disabled' class to the originally 
            //clicked link, causing it to skip this block of code
        }                       
    }                                   
);
```

Everything appears to work fine up to this point (though I may be missing something). Essentially I am creating `span` elements that come out looking like this in html:

`<span id="id_name" class="menu_name activated">Rendered Name</span>`

And since the above span does not have the `filter` class, I then try to create a new function in javascript (just as a test) to make the element responsive:

```
$('.activated').click(function()
    {
        alert('hi');
    }
);
```

But no luck. I've tried to re-render the dynamically created elements by nesting `div` or `a` inside the `span`, modifying the code as needed, but still nothing. I would like to keep the `span` because it's the only way I've found to wrap these dynamically generated elements to a second line within the `div` (`#active_filters`) where they are being created.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong given that I want to make the `activated` click() function responsive within each newly created `span` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your binding will not work if you attempt to bind to DOM elements contained in $('.activated') before creating them.  What this usually means is that you need that event listener to bind after creating.  If you're dynamically creating DOM elements, you need to do something like this:

```
var activeFilterNames = [];
   $('.filter').click(function()
      {
        if (!this.classList.contains('disabled'))
          {  
            activeFilterNames.push(this.textContent); 
            i = activeFilterNames.length;                                       
            var newFilter = document.createElement('span');
            newFilter.id = activeFilterNames[i-1];
            newFilter.className = this.className+" activated";
            newFilter.innerHTML = activeFilterNames[i-1];
            document.getElementById('active_filters').appendChild(newFilter);

            $('.activated').unbind('click');
            $('.activated').click(function()
                {
                    alert('hi');
                }
            );

            $("#active_filters > span").removeClass('filter');
            $(this).addClass('disabled');                                       
        }                       
    }                                   
);
```

Notice, before binding we unbind.  This makes sure that if you do this multiple times, you aren't binding 2, 3, 4 times to the same DOM element.

Comment: Thank you. I see what you're doing here. This is similar to the above solution, just done differently. Because the binding is done on loading the page, this is a way of resetting the class that didn't yet exist and giving it a bind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach click event on dynamically created elements. In jQuery this can be done using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method if you will pass your selector as second argument and attach click to some parent element, `body` for example:

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.activated', function()
    {
        alert('hi');
    }
);
```

Comment: Will definitely give this a shot. Can you explain briefly why I need to emulate live on dynamically created elements?

Comment: @user3822153 jQuery `on` method checks for DOM manipulations inside parent Node if selector was passed as second param.

Comment: This worked perfectly. And I think I get what you're saying. For my own understanding: Because the selector I had coded was set to respond to something that didn't yet exist, it didn't bind to anything when the page loaded, and it also could not bind to the dynamically created elements either (since they weren't there at load)? Correct?

Comment: The jQuery `on` method does not bind event handlers to dynamically create elements, rather it utilizes JavaScript Event Delegation -- The event handler is on the `<body>` element, given the example above.

Comment: @Greg Burghardt: Thank you.